# Why "too many values"?

Tags: sql

```
select MATNR, HKL from(
    select MATNR, HKL
      from BESTAND
     where LOK_NR >1
       and BEST_FREI =0
     union
    select MATNR, HKL from BESTAND
     where LOK_NR =1
      and BEST_FREI >0
)
 WHERE MATNR NOT IN(
    select MATNR, HKL
      from SONDER_AUFTRAG
     where GREIFLOK = 'J'
)
 GROUP BY MATNR, HKL
 ORDER BY MATNR, HKL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `not in`:

```
select MATNR, HKL
from (select MATNR, HKL
      from BESTAND
      where LOK_NR > 1 and BEST_FREI = 0
      union
      select MATNR, HKL
      from BESTAND
      where LOK_NR = 1 and BEST_FREI > 0
     )
WHERE MATNR NOT IN (select MATNR from SONDER_AUFTRAG where GREIFLOK = 'J' )
GROUP BY MATNR, HKL
ORDER BY MATNR, HKL ;
```

I think the query can be simplified to:

```
select distinct MATNR, HKL
from BESTAND b
where ((LOK_NR > 1 and BEST_FREI = 0) or
       (LOK_NR = 1 and BEST_FREI > 0)
      ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from SONDER_AUFTRAG sa
                  where sa.MATNR = b.MATNR and GREIFLOK = 'J'
                 )
order by MATNR, HKL ;
```

Notes:

- It is best to remove `union`, especially if `or` suffices.
- Both `union` and `group by` remove duplicates in your query.
- `not exists` is better than `not in` with a subquery, because the latter does not handle `NULL` values intuitively.

Comment: okay, this is the problem...damn! thx

But the result of my select is not right...

Comment: @Emjot . . . You should ask *another* question and provide sample data and desired results.  This answers the question that you did ask.